# How to collect a set of boolean values and return a final test combining all with 'AND' in Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to defining a function to return True if the pattern matches all the strings in the list. Like, matchAll(pattern, list).

My initial try is:

```
import re

def matchAll(pattern, list): 
    list_truth = list
    for i in list:
       list_truth[i] = re.search(pattern,i) != none
    if False in list_truth:
       return False
    else:
       return True
```

Yet, it doesn't work. Please let me know which part I was doing wrong. Much thanks!

For example, the sample input / output look like:

```
print matchAll('a', ['a', 'ab', 'abc']) # True
print matchAll('a', ['a', 'ab', 'bc'])  # False
print matchAll('(ab)?', ['a', 'ab', 'abc'])  # True
print matchAll('.', ['a', 'ab', 'abc'])      # True
print matchAll('.{2,3}', ['a', 'ab', 'abc']) # False
```

I have also modified my code as:

```
import re
def matchAll(pattern, list1): 
list_truth = list
for i in list1:
    if re.search(pattern,i) != None:
        pass
    else:
        return False
return True
```

Yet, it returns the correct result but I don't think it is a good way to construct the function. Does anybody has idea on how can I optimize it? Thanks!

Comment: is that your exact code? Can you also show sample inputs

Comment: I believe you will have problems if you use "list" as a parameter name, since you are shadowing a language constructor. Try to replace "list" with another name that is not a reserved word.

Comment: `for i in list` will iterate over the list values (i.e. strings), then you use them as indices, hence the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `all` for this (a Python builtin)

```
def match_all(pattern, items)
    return all(re.search(pattern, item) for item in items)
```

Also note that

- `list` is a builtin type, avoid using that for your variable names
- the return value for `re.search` is either an object (truthy) or `None` (falsy), which is why the return value can be used as booleany for `all`
- camelCase is often replaced with snake_case in Python (an ominous PEP-8 debate)

Comment: I was about to post the same as well! :) +1

Comment: +1 more people need to start using `all` and `any` while keeping in mind that they can take in a generator expression - I'm tired of seeing `all([x for x in y])`.

Comment: Agreed, generator expressions are the bombshizzle :)

Comment: @Bharel heh yeah, let's see if your comment is going to pay off :)

Comment: @akaIDIOT took it from [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251298/1658617) ;-)

Comment: @akaIDIOT Well, I guess no one will.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for the `all()` function. Here you go:

```
import re

def matchAll(pattern, list_): 
    return all(re.search(pattern,i) for i in list_)
```

Comment: Hah, beat me to it, it seems :P

Comment: @akaIDIOT I'm not sure, I believe you beat me to it. Oh well, may the odds be ever in your favor :P

Comment: Ah! I was coming here to post this exact answer! :) +1

Comment: This is the perfect version with list comprehension! Thanks Bharel and all you guys!

Comment: Hi @Mark Li, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: @MarkLi note that this is not a list comprehension, but rather a generator expression. The difference is subtle, but in many cases important. The latter is 'lazy', while the former will evaluate completely immediately. In this particular case, lazy is a good thing ;)

Comment: Thanks for the note @Bharel:) I thought I clicked the check-mark but guess it didn't go through.;( I just did again. Thanks again for your help on this question!